# Trusting report sent by `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only` header

Tags: http-headers, content-security-policy, trust

Is there a way to *validate* incoming report to `report-uri`. How can I trust sender of report if anybody can see `report-uri` in headers and send custom reports and abuse this endpoint.

In most cases received report is sent to administrator's email or definitely saved to some log file `csp.log`.

I implemented very strict rules on what CSP report must look like but still my concern is to receive couple of hundreds emails one day and find bloated log files.